# Decay rate of $|r_j^n-u_j^n|$, where $\{r_j^n\}_j$ and $\{u_j^n\}_j$ are partitions of $[s,t]$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Fix an interval $[s,t]\subset\Bbb R$, and consider on it two arbitrary *sequences* of partitions such that their mesh go to $0$.

So, for every $n\in\Bbb N$ we set
\begin{align*}
\pi^n:=\{s=r_0^n<r_1^n<\cdots<r_{k_n}^n<r_{k_n+1}^n=t\}\\
\sigma^n:=\{s=u_0^n<u_1^n<\cdots<u_{h_n}^n<u_{h_n+1}^n=t\}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
|\pi^n|:=\max_{1\le j\le k_n+1}|r_j^n-r_{j-1}^n|\to0\\
|\sigma^n|:=\max_{1\le j\le h_n+1}|u_j^n-u_{j-1}^n|\to0
\end{align*}

as $n\to+\infty$.

Observe that, possibly passing to a subsequence, we can wlog suppose that $h_n=k_n$.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to prove, exploiting the fact that the meshes go to $0$ and the possibility to pass to a subsequence, that there exists some absolute constant $C>0$ such that 
   $$
   |\pi^n|\le\frac C{k_n}\;?
   $$
2. Is it possibile to control
   $$
   |r_j^n-u_j^n|
   $$
   in terms of $|\pi^n|$ and $|\sigma^n|$? I mean: fixing $j$ and supposing wlog $u_j^n<r_j^n$, we have the following cases

$\bullet\;$ $r_{j-1}^n<\color{#c01}{u_j^n}<\color{#c01}{r_j^n}<u_{j+1}^n$ from which $|r_j^n-u_j^n|\le\min\{|\pi^n|,|\sigma^n|\}$.

$\bullet\;$ $\color{#c01}{u_{j}^n}<r_{j-1}^n<\color{#c01}{r_j^n}<u_{j+1}^n$ from which $|r_j^n-u_j^n|\le|\sigma^n|$.

$\bullet\;$ $r_{j-1}^n<\color{#c01}{u_{j}^n}<u_{j+1}^n<\color{#c01}{r_{j}^n}$ from which $|r_j^n-u_j^n|\le|\pi^n|$.

$\bullet\;$ $\color{#c01}{u_{j}^n}<r_{j-1}^n<u_{j+1}^n<\color{#c01}{r_{j}^n}$ from which $|r_j^n-u_j^n|\le|\pi^n|+|\sigma^n|$.

and till here all right; but one last case remains:

$\bullet\;$ $\color{#c01}{u_{j}^n}<u_{j+1}^n<r_{j-1}^n<\color{#c01}{r_{j}^n}$ from which $|r_j^n-u_j^n|\le|\pi^n|+|\sigma^n|+\alpha_j^n|r_j^n-u_j^n|$ for a suitable $\alpha_j^n\in]0,1[$ and thus 
$$
|r_j^n-u_j^n|\le\frac1{1-\alpha_j^n}\left(|\pi^n|+|\sigma^n|\right)\;.
$$
which is the worst case. Is it possible to show that
$$
\limsup_{n\to+\infty}\alpha_j^n<1\;\;?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to Question 1 is negative. Consider, for instance a sequence $\{\pi^n\}$ with $k_n=n$ and $|\pi^n|=r_1^n-r_0^n=(t-s)/\sqrt{n}$. The possibility to pass to a subsequence does not help at all, because a product $k_n|\pi^n|$ does not depend on an index of a subsequence member.

An answer to Question 2 is negative too. Consider, for instance sequences $\{\pi^n\}$ and $\{\sigma^n\}$ with $k_n=h_n=2n$, $r_n^n=s+(t-s)/3$, $u_n^n=s+2(t-s)/3$, and both $|\pi^n|$ and $|\sigma^n|$ tending to zero when $n$ tends to infinity. Nevertheless, $|r^n_n−u^n_n|=(t-s)/3$ for each $n$.